# Trying to evaluate an expression

Tags: ruby, rpn

I'm working on an RPN Calculator and think I'm almost there, except it's returning the expression not the solution.

```rb
def evaluate(expression)
  expression = expression.split

  operators = expression.select { |v| v =~ /\W/}
  operands  = expression.select { |v| v =~ /\d/}

  new_expression = operands.zip(operators)
  eval = new_expression.join
end
```

This should return `-7`:

```rb
puts evaluate('5 8 + 4 - 5 *')
#=> 5+8-4*5
```

Comment: You can't get operator precedence right that way. The correct result needs to be 45, not -7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval = new_expression.join
```

This calls `new_expression.join` and stores the result in a local variable called `eval`. Since you never use that local variable, you could as well just have written:

```
new_expression.join
```

If it was your intention to call Ruby's `eval` method with the result of `new_expression.join` as its argument, you should remove the assignment operator:

```
eval new_expression.join
```

That said using `eval` to evaluate the expression is only a good idea if you're only ever evaluating trusted input.

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly what you've written, i. e. it makes variable `eval` with String given. Solution:

```
def evaluate(expression)
  expression = expression.split

  operators = expression.select { |v| v =~ /\W/}
  operands  = expression.select { |v| v =~ /\d/}

  new_expression = operands.zip(operators)
  eval new_expression.join
end

puts evaluate('5 8 + 4 - 5 *')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a local variable called `eval`, but you really want to call `Kernel#eval` with your expression as parameter like so:

```
eval operands.zip(operators).join
```